# removing input field value by jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

My problem is that the form automatically loads the value of field company name.
However  this is the required field.
I only want to remove the previous load value to be empty, and let the user to fill the input field.

For example previously when I filled the form I put value tadipar in the field, now  the  value tadipar is occurring for next time form filling also

I haven't tried anything because I dont have any clue what to do with this?
any suggestions so that i can do

[image: view image]

```
'company' => [
                'company_name'    => [
                    'label'       => __( 'Company name', 'wp-job-manager' ),
                    'label_two'       => __( 'Enter the name of the company', 'wp-job-manager' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'required'    => true,
                    //'placeholder' => __( 'Enter the name of the company', 'wp-job-manager' ),
                    'priority'    => 1,
                    'labelstar' =>  '*',
                ],
```

the field is coming from the object above, it doesn't have value argument, that makes so difficult to find the code from 100000 files

additional informantion:- i am working on workscout wordpress theme, the from is built in wp-job-mananger plugin

Comment: I am voting to close this question. You expect a solution but cannot even paste the code instead of posting screen shots

Comment: `window.addEventListener("load",function() { document.getElementById("company_name").value="";})`

Comment: _“from above the field is comming from”_ - that is only data, some sort of configuration. You have not even told us _what for_, meaning what form builder plugin or whatever this is input _for_. All we know is that WordPress is involved, but that does not contain any default form builder as far as I know. So your question here is pretty much unclear, because it lacks proper context.

Comment: giving undefined errro\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to pass empty double-quotes in the placeholder, and value also empty.

```
'placeholder' => '',
'value' => ''
```

but due to some other possible functions autofilling this fields, you can always try this hardcore solution

type this in your console.log

```
document.getElementById("company_name").value=""
```

and you'l see it working, and that proofs that something else ich mixing the code

Comment: i already did this before but it dosent make any change.

Comment: So you must be changing it at the wrong place. This is definitely WP and many more things might be involved. I guarantee you that if you set this values it would work

Comment: type this in your console.log document.getElementById("company_name").value="" and you'l see it working, and that proofs that something else ich mixing the code

Comment: thanks buddy you make my problem solved.... so so much thankyou

Comment: yes offcourse, just copy and paste the answer from commnent to the answer section so that i can vote up for the right one

Answer (score 0):

For me it sounds like that your browser is automaticly completing the field.

Set the parameter `autocomplete="off"` for the field (or perhaps for the entire form)